# Understanding bound and free variables in LISP

Tags: scope, lisp, sicp

I'm reading *SICP*, and the topic of bound and free variables has come up. However, I am confused about it. Does the term "bound variables" only apply to variables that are formal parameters? In addition, the text says that a procedure definition "binds" its formal parameters. This confuses me with the fact that some people say that we "bind" a value to a variable. Obviously, the term seems to mean different things when we're talking about different types of variables. Could someone clear up what a bound variable is and what binding means? Finally, in contrast to a bound variable, what is free variable? How does all of this relate to scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are only two types of variables. Global and lexical. You can actually think of global as a changeable root of the lexical scope and in that case there is only one type of variables.

A bound variable is the formal parameters of the current procedure and everything else, which either is global or bound from previous nested calls, are free variables.

Example:

```
(lambda (x)
  (let ((y (+ x x))) ; + is free x is bound
    (+ x y)))        ; + and x is free, y is bound
```

Remember `let` is ust syntactic sugar so it's really the same as this:

```
(lambda (x)
  ((lambda (y)
     (+ x y)) ; + and x is free, y is bound
   (+ x x)))  ; + is free x is bound
```

In the inner lambda with `y` as bound variable `+` and `x` are free. In the outer lambda `x` is bound and `+` is free. `+` might be a global.

Comment: @ Sylwester What if, in some arbitrary procedure, I wrote `(define a 2)`. That is, I'm assigning the variable a the value 2. In this case, would the variable be bound or free? Or do these terms, bound and free, only apply to the formal parameters of procedures?

Comment: @milesdavis `define` inside a procedure is syntax sugar for `letrec` which is very similar to `y` in my `let` example.